# list of objects inside the same object in java

Tags: java, oop, methods

I have the next situation:

```
public class Network {
   protected int mask;
   protected IPv4Address address;

   public Network(IPv4Address address, int maskLength) {
    blahblah
   }
   public mymethod() {
    Network[] privatnetworks = {new Network(new IPv4Address("10.0.0.0"), 8), new Network(new IPv4Address("172.16.0.0"), 12)}
}
```

Here each time I call mymethod I need to create list of objects which is unefficient for me. Can I somehow create it once and use it for all my method? Sorry if this question is simple or stupid - I'm a newbie in java.

Comment: Read about `Singleton` design pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Network` a `static` variable, it will be initialized only once.

```
static Network[] privatnetworks = {new Network(new IPv4Address("10.0.0.0"), 8), new Network(new IPv4Address("172.16.0.0"), 12)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the variable as a instance variable:

```
public class Network {
   protected int mask;
   protected IPv4Address address;
   Network[] privatnetworks = {new Network(new IPv4Address("10.0.0.0"), 8), new Network(new IPv4Address("172.16.0.0"), 12)}

   public Network(IPv4Address address, int maskLength) {
    blahblah
   }
   public mymethod() {
    }
```

Comment: I tried without word static - it is compiled but not launched. Failure is at Network.<init>(Network.java:4) many many times. I think maybe recursion...

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public class Network {
   protected int mask;
   protected IPv4Address address;

   private static  Network[] privatnetworks = {new Network(new IPv4Address("10.0.0.0"), 8), new Network(new IPv4Address("172.16.0.0"), 12)}

   public Network(IPv4Address address, int maskLength) {
    blahblah
   }
   public mymethod() {

}
```